# How to show number of customers having same createdAt and lastVisited dates

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to show number of customers having same create date and `lastVisited` date in mongodb.

Here is my database code:

```
"customer.insert": function(name, phone) {
    Customers.insert({
        name,
        phone,
        points: 0,
        restaurant: this.userId,
        createdAt: new Date(), // current time
        customerBills: [newBillObject],
        lastVisited: new Date(),
        points: pointAdded
    });
}
```

Now, I want to display number of customers having same `createdAt` and `lastVisited` date on client side. How can i do it ?

Comment: where is the lastVisited date?

Comment: `return Customers.insert({
                name: bill.name,
                phone: bill.phone,
                points: 0,
                code:bill.code,
                restaurant: this.userId,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                customerBills: [newBillObject],
                lastVisited: new Date(),
                points: pointAdded
            });`

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to push additional info to your question instead of the comment fields.

Comment: And it's not the number of people having the same createdAt date and the number of people having the same lastVisited date? But the number of people who share the same createAt and the same lastVisited date?

Comment: yess, i want to show number of users that are recently inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general non-performant solution would use the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** operator as:

```
db.customers.count({ "$where": "this.lastVisited == this.createdAt" })
```

However, bear in mind that this won't perfom very well since a query operation with the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** operator calls the JavaScript engine to evaluate Javascript code on every document and checks the condition for each. This is very slow as MongoDB evaluates non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** query operations before **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** expressions and non-**[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** query statements may use an index. It is advisable to combine with indexed queries if you can so that the query may be faster. However, it's recommended to use JavaScript expressions and the **[`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where)** operator as a last resort when you can't structure the data in any other way, or when you are dealing with a small subset of data.

---

A better solution would be to use the aggregation framework, especially using **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** which works by proccessing a logical condition within **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to keep the documents in the collection where the logical condition are met or **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to remove the documents where the condition is not met i.e. the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** expression evaluates to false. Thus your resulting pipeline will consist of documents that only satisfy the given condition.

You can subsequently use the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to aggregate the documents and get the count.

---

The following example demonstrates this concept:

**Populate Test Collection:**

```
db.test.insert([
    { a: 1, b: 1 },
    { a: 3, b: 1 },
    { a: 2, b: 2 },
    { a: 1, b: 7 },
    { a: 4, b: 4 },
    { a: 1, b: 1 }
])
```

**Using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact):**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": ["$a", "$b"] },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Ouput:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577cd1de8b29cbf37abe1939"),
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577cd1de8b29cbf37abe193b"),
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 2
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577cd1de8b29cbf37abe193d"),
    "a" : 4,
    "b" : 4
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577cd1de8b29cbf37abe193e"),
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 1
}
```

**Aggregating:**

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": ["$a", "$b"] },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "count" : 4
}
```

---

Now putting this altogether and applying that to your collection:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": ["$lastVisited", "$createdAt"] },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```